# Detecting data types in Python

Tags: python

I am new at Python and I am not to sure about data types. If I coded
 `wordfile = open("Sentence.txt","w")`. What data type would "wordfile" be?

Comment: Try `type(wordfile)`. But that's a pretty meaningless bit of information. Why do you need to know this?

Comment: @MorganThrapp sometimes it's not about why, it's just because curiosity is human nature. Yes knowing that might not be useful, but at least he/she/code knows.

Comment: It can be useful sometimes. An example would be a function argument that could have different data types, and depending on that the function treats them in a different way by doing for instance: `if isinstance(list, argument):`

Answer (score 2):

It's a `Text IO Wrapper`, i.e. handler for IO operations.

```
>>> wordfile = open('file.txt', 'w')
>>> wordfile
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='file.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1255'>
>>> type(wordfile)
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
```

`open` and this class are contained in the `io` module, but can be accessed without import `io`. You can, however, import the `io` module and use the `io.open`method directly.

---

As official documentation claims:

> **class io.TextIOWrapper**
>
> A buffered text stream over a `BufferedIOBase`
> binary stream.

means, `TextIOWrapper` uses `BufferedIOBase`
binary stream as a 'channel' for a text stream, so it can handle text files.

> **class io.BufferedIOBase**
>
> Base class for binary streams that support some kind of buffering.